# SQL filter all values in one column but not in another one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a query which is as follows:

```
SELECT t1.blah , t2.blah
FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

So the results looks like

```
t1.blah   t2.blah
=================
390       400
401       401
501       501
36        36
```

What I look for is to extract all values that are in t1.blah but never in t2.blah. In my example I should get as final result the value 390.

I tried to do some test with `HAVING` but I did not succeed. How can I achieve that in mysql for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put one more condition on `blah` not matching in both the tables:

```sql
SELECT t1.blah , t2.blah
FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 
            ON t1.id = t2.id
               AND t1.blah <> t2.blah
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland Personally, I always prefer INNER JOIN over LEFT JOIN (as long as it can be done with INNER JOIN), as I have found it more performant. On a different topic, any experience with `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` function introduced in 5.7+ ? I am observing that MySQL does not use any index when using JSON_ARRAYAGG compared to creating JSON using GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT functions.

Comment: *"Personally, I always prefer INNER JOIN over LEFT JOIN (as long as it can be done with INNER JOIN), as I have found it more performant."* yes i removed mine comment but you totally are right.. LEFT JOIN would force MySQL into needed to fully table/index scan the left table before the LEFT JOIN clause..  For some reason it never popped into mine mind into using a exclusion inner join for missing values selection/checking how bizar is that..

Comment: *"On a different topic, any experience with JSON_ARRAYAGG() function introduced in 5.7+ ? I am observing that MySQL does not use any index when using JSON_ARRAYAGG compared to creating JSON using GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT functions."* Make a question with examples on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ you know as good as i that is not really answerable here in the comments ;-)

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah I am just doing some testing on different patches of 5.7 before coming to a conclusion, and  posting a question (I might even do a bug report at mysql website).. Will let you know once done.

Comment: ok i could make a little snoop in the source code how `JSON_ARRAYAGG` is implemented, MySQL is known for adding new features "fast" and optimisation on those features might happen monthes, years after or not at all..

Comment: *" Will let you know once done. "* and whats the result what did you find out about the `JSON_ARRAYAGG` tending to not use indexes?

Comment: @RaymondNijland stuck in some other optimization acitivities :-/ will try to post a question to dba.se by end of this week; will update you once done.

Comment: @RaymondNijland maybe you can help here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59499000/2469308 .. Regarding `JSON_ARRAYAGG` thing, I just could not find time to do more studies and prepare the question. If I come across it again, I will definitely do more testing then, and post it.